# Understanding the proof of Theorem of Ostrowski

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading the proof of Theorem of Ostrowski (1921) in complex analysis provided in “Real and complex analysis” of Rudin page 321 or in “A course in complex analysis” of Zakeri page 303 but don’t understand one part of it.

> *Hypothesis.* $f$ holomorphic with radius of convergence $1$, $1$ is a regular point of $f$.
>
> *Proof.* $D(1,r)$ is a disk in which $f$ extends holomorphically (since $1$ is regular). Let’s define $U = D(0,1) \cup D(1,r)$. Consider the polynomial:
>
> $$P(w) = \frac{1}{2}w^N(w+1)$$
>
> We have $P(1)=1$ and $|P(w)| < 1$ if $|w| \leq 1$ with $w \neq 1$ Then there exists $\epsilon$ (sufficiently small) such that $P(D(0,1+\epsilon)) \subset U$.

I don’t understand the **last deduction.** Rudin does not clarify why and Zakeri uses the continuity of $P$ but I don’t see why this is true.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: The $(w+1)/2$ factor in $P$ ensures $|P| \le \delta<1$ for $|z| \le 1$ away from a small neighborhood $V$ of $1$ so $P(D(0,1+\epsilon)-V) \subset$ unit disc, while since $P(1)=1$ we have $P(V) \subset D(1,r)$

Comment: you have $|z|<=1$ and $z \neq 1$  implies $ |P(z)| <1 $ so how do you get for $z$ such $1<|z|<1+\epsilon$ the intended $|P(z)| < 1$ ?

Comment: The point is that there is a small neighborhood $V$ of $1$ and a $\delta <1$ st $|P(w)| \le \delta$ for $w\in D(0,1) -V$ since $|1+w|/2 \le \delta$ there; then by continuity, there is $\epsilon >0$ st $|P(w)| < 1$ for $w\in D(0,1+\epsilon) -V$; shrinking $\epsilon >0$ if needed and using $P(1) =1$ we also have $P(D(0,1+\epsilon) \cap V) \subset D(1,r)$

Comment: Thank you. I think I get the idea.